# Nestjs- How to use a repository outside a module

Tags: repository, nestjs, typeorm, dto, class-validator

I am new to nestjs typeorm
I am trying to validate user existence through dto as per this method
https://dev.to/avantar/custom-validation-with-database-in-nestjs-gao
just the problem is, I want to keep all the dto's outside the user module.
And keep the ValidatorConstraintInterface in seperate util file
but I am not getting access to the repository in the util file.

> this.userRepository returns undefined.

how to provide and then call the entity or repo outside the modules.
Any help would mean a lot. Thank you